# Using JNI libraries in an Eclipse Java project

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have inherited a jar file with two JNI class files and related libraries (.so files). I am not familiar with c++ or JNI. How do I reference these in my Java project in Eclipse?

So far, I have created a Java project, added the jar file as an external jar to the buildpath and then have attached the folder containing the jni libraries using Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab, expand the jar file (containing the class files) and edit "Native library location".

I have a driver program in Java with a main method which makes the jni object. Eclipse says "ObjectName cannot be resolved to a type".

Why would this happen even though the class files are in the build path?

Answer (score 1):

I have just put all the libraries under /src/main/resources. 
 Right click on the project and go to Properties>JavaBuildPath. In the Libraries section expand the jar you need the libraries for and  click on "Native library location", then press "Edit..".
You just need to give the /src/main/resources path as location.
Then in the "Order and Export" section of the Properties>JavaBuildPath you need to make sure that /src/main/java is above /src/main/resources.

Answer (score 0):

In the Java file, where you instanciate your JNI defined object, make sure you have imported the class files:

> **import** your.jni.classes;

I suggest you have a look here, at the video:
http://mmbtools.crc.ca/content/view/53/78/
(look at this video on Youtube and set the resolution to 720px to see clearly)

It is a good step-by-step example of how to integrate JNI classes in a Java application, in Eclipse. It is pretty much what you're trying to do.

Hope it helps,